# making a copy for a variable

Tags: c++, pointers, copy

Consider this piece of code:

```
int *a, *b;
a = foo();
if (a)
   b = a;
a = bar();
```

The problem is, when `a` updates by calling `bar()`, `b` also updates. However I want to make a backup by using `b = a`. What is the problem then?

Comment: I can't understand the question. Could be be more clear about what you mean when you say "when a updates" and "b also updates".

Comment: @David Heffernan: I mean when `a = bar()` executes, `b` is also changed to the new value of `a`

Comment: No, that is simply not possible.

Comment: You appear to be asserting that assigning to `a` results in `b` changing. That's not possible.

Comment: The code snippet you provide [doesn't behave the way you claim](http://ideone.com/oelh0). Can you provide instead a **complete** program (keep it as short as possible. 10 lines is fine) that demonstrates the problem you are having?  See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the updated version? You are comparing a pointer to an instance of a type. :-\.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *a, *b;
b = new int;

a = foo();
if (a)
   *b = *a;
a = bar();
...
delete(b);
```

(The value at address a is assigned to the value at address b.)

What you are doing right now is making a and b point to the **same** place in memory. Then, if the value in a or b is updated, they pointers both point to the new value.

By the way, unless `bar()` returns a pointer, you probably want `*a = foo()` and `*a = bar()`.

Comment: `b` is uninitialized (i.e. contains undefined memory address), so this would a an access violation.

Comment: Well, I wasn't providing full code here, but I suppose you are right. Fixed.

Comment: Now you have a memory leak. And are frowned upon by C++ gods for using  `malloc` instead of `new` ;)

Comment: I didn't even realize that this is C++. xD... I don't believe that I've introduced any memory leaks into the code, but if you could enlighten me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You have a `new` without matching `delete`.

Comment: This **is** a partial code fragment, but you are still right. (I could have sworn that I wrote that in. xD...)

Comment: BTW, if `foo()` returned an `int`, it would be impossible to assign it to `int*` without cast, so OP's code would not even compile (not to mention that the cast would be a really bad idea). So `foo()` must be returning `int*`. Ditto for `bar()`.

Comment: -1 "What you are doing right now is making a and b point to the same place in memory." Wrong. The pointers are not modified in `*b = *a`, the pointees are.

Comment: Sorry for nit-picking @Zéychin, I'm sure you know about all that, but I don't think the OP does, so it's probably better not so suggest to him that allocating memory without eventually freeing it would be OK.

Comment: Check the original post, @PaulManta. He assigns the pointer b to pointer a.

Comment: No, @BrankoDimitrijevic, you're quite right and I'm a little tired. You're doing good by the community.

Answer (score 1):

You could just back up the value of a:

```
int *a, b;
a = foo();
if (a)
   b = *a;
a = bar();
```

or if you want to keep `b` as a pointer:

```
...
   *b = *a;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

if a == b, then bar() is changing the value at a, not assigning a new a. This makes the most sense memory wise. If what you care about is the actual integer, not the address, instead of assigning b = a assign *b = *a.

Answer (score 0):

The...

```
int *a;
// ...
a = foo();
```

...would not even compile if the function was declared as `int foo();`, so I'll assume it's declared as `int* foo();`. Ditto for `int* bar();`.

Don't return a raw pointer like this. It might not be clear whether caller should `delete` it or not. The good documentation can only *partially* resolve this problem (human beings have a tendency of ignoring the documentation from time to time). Why not just copy the integer *value*, or at least return a *reference* to integer in case it really needs to be shared?

That being said, in your particular case, `foo()` and `bar()` apparently use the same int "object" internally, so `a` continues to point to the same object as `b` even after `bar()` has modified it.